# AutoMapper condition expression one way

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a mapping which looks like:

```
CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
        .ForMember(
            dto => dto.Id,
            expression => expression.Condition(src => src.HasIdentity)
        ).ReverseMap();
```

Only my src object has the `HasIdentity` property, will the `ReverseMap()` fail and should I remove this and create a seperated mapping in the other direction without the condition?